# Import latest CSV into Excel based on dynamic date property of file

Tags: vba, excel

Stackbros

I have some VBA which I'm using to import a .csv file from a specified folder into Excel. Once imported the script performs some other transformations such as delimiting and offsetting. See below.

```
Sub OpenTextFile ()

Dim FilePath As String

FilePath = "C:\Foldername\Foldername\Foldername\File_name.CSV"

Open FIlePath For Input As #1

row_number = 0

Do Until EOF(1)

    Line Input #1, LineFromFile

    LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ",")

    ActiveCell.Offset (row_number, 0).Value = LineItems (2)
    ActiveCell.Offset (row_number, 1).value = LineItems (1)
    ActiveCell.Offset (row_number, 2).Value = LineItems (0)

    row_number = row_number + 1 

    Loop

    Close #1

End Sub
```

What I really want to do is modify this so that when I run this I'm alsways importing the latest file from the folder, based on the date property of the file in the folder.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this routine.  It is rather old but I think it does what you want.  If not, it should give you some ideas.

```
Function NewestFileName(ByVal Path As String, ByVal FileTemplate As String) As String

  ' * Path          Folder in which to search for files
  ' * FileTemplate  File name specification of the file required.  For example:
  '                     MyFile*.xls
  ' * Finds, and returns the name of, the newest file in folder Path with a name
  '   that matches FileTemplate.  Returns "" if no matching file is found.
  ' 25Jul11  Copied from RiskRegisterControl V43.xls.
  ' 22Nov11  Name changed from NewestFile to NewestFileName to match NextFileName.
  ' 20Apr12  Minor improvements

  Dim FileDateCrnt              As Date
  Dim FileDateNewest            As Date
  Dim FileNameCrnt              As String
  Dim FileNameNewest            As String

  If Right(Path, 1) <> "\" Then
    Path = Path & "\"
  End If

  FileNameCrnt = Dir$(Path & FileTemplate)
  If FileNameCrnt = "" Then
    NewestFileName = ""
    Exit Function
  End If

  FileNameNewest = FileNameCrnt
  FileDateNewest = FileDateTime(Path & FileNameCrnt)
  Do While True
    FileNameCrnt = Dir$
    If FileNameCrnt = "" Then Exit Do
    FileDateCrnt = FileDateTime(Path & FileNameCrnt)
    If FileDateCrnt > FileDateNewest Then
      FileNameNewest = FileNameCrnt
      FileDateNewest = FileDateCrnt
    End If
  Loop

  NewestFileName = FileNameNewest

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @Tony Dallimore this was a great help. I modded the code slightly and appended some other transformational stuff but it seems to work a treat. So grateful.

Comment: @jimiclapton  I am pleased it was helpful; I use it a lot. I do not like saving over the top of an input file in case something has gone wrong.  Most of files have names such as "Xxxxxx V9.xxx".  I have a matching macro which finds the trailing digits of the file name, adds 1 to those digits and creates "Xxxxxx V10.xxx" which is the name under which I save the next version.